# Are inconsistent equations linearly independent or linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a doubt...

I know that the systems of equations:

$$\begin{cases} 
x+y=4\\
2x+2y=8
\end{cases}$$

is LD, and:

$$\begin{cases} 
3x=4\\
2y=5
\end{cases}$$

is LI, but what if I have?

$$\begin{cases} 
x+y=4\\
x+y=0
\end{cases}$$

In this case the equations doesn't make sense, are they classified as LI or LD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations $x+y=4;x+y=0$ are linearly independent because you cannot use one of them to obtain the other. In other words both yield different graphs. If they were dependent they would produce identical graphs.